# Can a function marked as noexcept have exceptions inside?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, noexcept

Let's say that I have a function marked as `noexcept` but there's a line of code inside that can throw. That line of code will be in a try block and the exception will be caught. Does that cause anything?

```
void MyFunc() noexcept
{
    try {
        throw std::exception("...");
    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        // I'll deal with it here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly legal, as long as the exception doesn't leak out of the function.

> An implementation shall not reject an expression merely because when executed it throws or might throw
>   an exception that the containing function does not allow.

[except.spec/11 in C++11]

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your quote applies to `void MyFunc() noexcept { throw std::exception("..."); }` (without the `try`/`catch`), and merely states that the compiler must not reject it, it doesn't cover how the exception is handled at run-time.

Answer (score 10):

Searching for an exception handler is done from the inside out, searching one level less deep whenever nothing is found to handle the exception.

> **15.3 Handling an exception [except.handle]**
>
> 4 The handlers for a try block are tried in order of appearance. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> 6 If no match is found among the handlers for a try block, the search for a matching handler continues in a dynamically surrounding try block of the same thread.
>
> **15.4 Exception specifications [except.spec]**
>
> 9 Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler (15.3) encounters the outermost block of a function with an *exception-specification* that does not allow the exception, then,
>
> [... `std::unexpected()` or `std::terminate()` is called. ]

The only time `noexcept(true)` has a visible effect is if an exception is thrown from inside the function, and no matching handler is present. No special effect is specified for an an exception with a matching handler, so that must run the same as in a `noexcept(false)` function.