# Can an uninitialised std::optional or boost::optional constructor throw?

Tags: c++, option-type, noexcept, boost-optional

Can either of the following template methods be declared `noexcept`?

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> foo(const T& value) // noexcept?
{
    try {
        // code possibly returning a T or a std::nullopt
    } catch(...) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}

template <typename T>
boost::optional<T> bar(const T& value) // noexcept?
{
    try {
        // code possibly returning a T or a boost::none
    } catch(...) {
        return boost::none;
    }
}
```

In other words, can an uninitialised `std/boost::optional` (`nullopt/none`) throw?

Comment: Not sure if I follow the question. An unitialized optional will throw if you attempt to extract it's value through `value()`.

Comment: Sure, but can the *construction* of an uninitialised optional throw (i.e. can the functions in the question be declared `noexcept`)?

Comment: Default constructor of `optional` is `noexcept`. Is this your question?

Comment: Yes... that would be a nicer way of putting it! Do you have references?

Comment: with a `try-catch` block that doesn't rethrow, you can declare the functions `noexcept` anyway, right? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28975065/27678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default constructor of optional is declared `noexcept`, as per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/optional.

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing an `optional<T>` from a value of T (probably a `T&&`), which in turn calls the corresponding ctor of T. If T's ctor throws, then so does optional's ctor. Depending upon what the missing code inside the `try{}` block does, your exception specification should be something like

```
noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value)
```

or

```
noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T>::value)
```